# How to set maximum number of fails in testthat?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I notice with unit testing using the testthat package in R, when you get 10 or more fails, you get the output message:
`Maximum number of failures exceeded; quitting early. You can increase this number by setting options(testthat.progress.max_fails)`

However, I can't see how and where I can change the options. When I run what is suggested: `options(testthat.progress.max_fails)`,
I get:
`Error in options(testthat.progress.max_fails): object 'testthat.progress.max_fails' not found`

Any ideas how I can raise the number of max errors?

Comment: Just set the option : `options(testthat.progress.max_fails = 100)`

Comment: Many thanks @Waldi. Worked.